# Delete /usr/bin/python3 on mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, python-3.8

I am trying to remove all my python for reinstall them properly.
I have check lot of stack overflow topic, and now I am at this point :

when I am doing

```
which python3
```

I have :

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

also, doing

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python*
```

give :

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75  4 avr  2020 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82  4 avr  2020 /usr/bin/python-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75  4 avr  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75  4 avr  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82  4 avr  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31488 10 jul 00:26 /usr/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76  4 avr  2020 /usr/bin/pythonw -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76  4 avr  2020 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

so clearly my last python3 to remove is : /usr/bin/python3

but when I am doing :

```
rm python3
```

I have the question :

```
override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel restricted,compressed for python3? y       
rm: python3: Operation not permitted
```

and here I am completely block, what is the next step ?

I am doing that because that point on a python3.8 (install by brew) and what I want is a python3.7
so if you have a better solution than delete this version to reinstalle 3.7 I am also open to a solution, I am stuck with this issue

thanks

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) has instructions on how to install specific versions of formulas using homebrew

Answer (score 0):

Forget about deleting python3 under `/usr/bin/python3`. Just simply download python again from official website. It will install a package which will automatically save under `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3`. It simply worked fine for me and I'm not facing any issues.

I was also a new Mac User. I don't remember how I installed python the first time. But it installed under `/usr/bin/python3`.
You can check this by running --> `which python3`.

I was facing problems using the packages I installed with pip. Pip was installing the packages under the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip3`.
You can check this again by running `which pip`.

Thus the clashes.

You may have seen or if you get an error like this -->

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
```

If that's the case, Just download new python!

Answer (score -1):

A followup on this post from 2022. I meet the same problem today. I did my research on the Internet and experimented all of those on my own. Unfortunately, none succeeds. All I can do now is to summarize those for the latecomers, and please let me know if a good solution comes up.

---

First I tried is the `sudo` method. Which gives the same "Operation not permitted" error. Which is weird. Some posts accuse the system as I am also using MacOS. I am not sure if that is also the case of kilag. Anyway, as a response from `ls -ld /usr/bin`, we can see the operation should be allowed:

```
drwxr-xr-x  1012 root  wheel  32384  9 May 14:30 /usr/bin
```

There is also a post mentioning flags which can be revealed by `ls -lO`. Their programs are successfully deleted after changing the flags by `chflags`. However, as `ls -lO` gives `restricted, compressed` flag for python3 directory which is not even defined in `chflags`. I pause there.

Answer (score -5):

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
```

or

```
sudo rm -r usr/bin/python3
```